# CS50: PSET6 [DNA] Loop miscounts longest run of STR

Tags: python, cs50

I've posted a question on cs50 stackexchange but haven't gotten an answer, i've been stuck on this problem set for a week now...

Link: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/37281/pset6-dna-loop-miscounts-longest-run-of-str

But to Summarize...My code is supposed to iterate over a DNA sequence and count the longest consecutive run of a Short Tandem Repeat (STR) then compare that with a given database in order to identify who this DNA belongs to.

Right now i'm working on counting the longest run of an STR, I believe my logic is sound but i can't identify why my code miscounts an STR most of the time.

```
For clarity: 
if the expected output is [18, 23, 35, 13, 11, 19, 14, 24]
the actual output is [18, 23, 36, 13, 15, 19, 15, 26]
```

The PSET Material: https://cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/psets/6/dna/dna.zip

Basically you pass the database as the 1st command line argument and the DNA sequence as the 2nd. In the case of the example used above i used large.csv 6.txt

I've been stuck on this problem set for way too long and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
# modules
import sys
import csv

# ensure proper usage
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    sys.exit()

database = sys.argv[1]
sequence = sys.argv[2]

run = 0
longrun = 0
STR_Count = []

# open database
with open(database, newline='') as csvfile:
    db_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # a list of STRs
    STR = list(next(db_reader))
    STR.pop(0)

# open DNA sequence file
with open(sequence, newline='') as txtfile:
    seq_reader = txtfile.read()

# for every STR
for x in range(len(STR)):
    # iterate over the entire sequence
    for y in range(len(seq_reader)):
        # if STR matches sub-string
        if STR[x] == seq_reader[y:y + len(STR[x])]:
            run += 1
            # update index
            y = y + len(STR[x])

            # if STR no longer matches sub-string
            if not STR[x] == seq_reader[y:y + len(STR[x])]:
                if run > longrun:
                    longrun = run
                    run = 0
    STR_Count.append(longrun)
    run = 0
    longrun = 0
print(STR_Count)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what your data looks like and what value you'd pass as the 2nd argument. Also, please update your expected outcome and actual outcome to match the example data you provide, so people can replicate your problem and provide a possible solution.

Comment: Done! i added the Material i'm working with and the clarifications required. I also updated my code so that you can replicate the problem.

Comment: Is this the answer of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61447673/11000382

Comment: it is. Thank you so much!!!